# Disable 2 buttons in flash after so many button clicks

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm making a word game in flash and I want to be able to disable 2 buttons after a button count reaches a certain value but the code I have made disables the button after just the one click. I've done similar code to this for other languages so I didn't think it'd be too hard I used the same basic syntax. Would I perhaps need to right a for loop or have I just made a basic error in this if statement

```
on (release){
var i;

if(i >= 6)
{
    vowel.enabled = false;
    cons.enabled = false;
}   

i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use button index value like this

```
on (release){

// somewhere you have to set index values your vowel and cons buttons 
// notice that you shouldn't set these index on(release) function. You should set button index values global scope.

vowel.index = 0;
const.index = 1;

if(this.i >= 6)
{
    if(i != vowel.index && i != cons.index) {
        // enable other buttons this condition ignores vowel and cons buttons.
    }
    vowel.enabled = false;
    cons.enabled = false;
}   

   this.i++;
}
```

Comment: by the way "const" is the reserved variable in actionscript. I suggest you change "constBtn" or another name...